# Reference for Poincare Inequality

Tags: probability, references

I am looking for a good introductory paper on (probabilistic) Poincare inequalities.
Something that a beginning graduate student can learn from.

Recall that the Poincare inequality states that
\begin{align}
Var(f(X)) \le c E[ \| \nabla f(X)\|^2] ,
\end{align}
for some $c \ge 0$ and smooth enough function $f$.

I am especially interested in texts that property show when these inequalities holds and explain properties of a constant $c$.

Comment: In case you haven’t already checked, the first place I would start would be *Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence* by Boucheron, Lugosi, Massart (2016) and the chapter bibliographies.